# Why does CURRENT_DATE contains time in Oracle Mode?

Tags: oracle, hsqldb

When I connect to

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:lbw;sql.syntax_ora=true
```

the statement

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM dual
```

results in

```
2014-01-31 10:35:54
```

This is in opposite to connections without Oracle syntax mode, where `CURRENT_DATE` doesn't contain time.
As described in the [HSQLDB documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#mtc_compatibility_oracle), `DATE` is interpreted as `TIMESTAMP(0)` in Oracle syntax mode. But in Oracle 10g itself, `CURRENT_DATE` behaves as expected (without time).

This difference seems to include `DATE` fields in general.

Why does HSQLDB behave this way?
Is there a way to disable the automatic conversion?

Comment: No. `current_date` **does** contain a time in Oracle, your SQL client might just not display it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18937

Comment: Ok, and does the time part affects comparison of CURRENT_DATE with DATE fields?

Comment: I know nothing about HSQLDB but something called Oracle mode is [expected to include time components when calling `CURRENT_DATE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18937). Do you want to rephrase the question as "why doesn't regular mode have time"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [same HSQLDB documentation you linked to](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#sgc_datetime_types):

> **Datetime types**
>
> HSQLDB fully supports datetime and interval types and operations,
>   including all relevant optional features, as specified by the SQL
>   Standard since SQL-92. The two groups of types are complementary.
>
> The DATE type represents a calendar date with YEAR, MONTH and DAY
>   fields.
>
> The TIME type represents time of day with HOUR, MINUTE and SECOND
>   fields, plus an optional SECOND FRACTION field.
>
> The TIMESTAMP type represents the combination of DATE and TIME types.

The [Oracle compatibility section](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#mtc_compatibility_oracle) says:

> - The DATE type is interpreted as TIMESTAMP(0) in ORA syntax mode.

Oracle's [`DATE` data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330) "contains the datetime fields `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, and `SECOND`". So it's equivalent to an HSQLDB `TIMESTAMP(0)` data type, and in Oracle mode it is treated as such.

Oracle dates always have a time component, even if it is all zeros for midnight. If your SQL client doesn't show it by default you can see that with `select to_char(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`, as others have already pointed out.

In normal non-Oracle mode HSQLDB is just treating the value as an SQL-standard `DATE` and dropping the time portion; in Oracle mode it preserves the time. There doesn't seem to be any way to selectively enable some aspects of the Oracle mode, so you're stuck with the time - really not sure why that is an issue though since it's just reflecting the data you have in your database. If you want to ignore the time you could always `select trunc(current_date)`, which will take the time back to midnight; but it will still show as `2014-01-31 00:00:00` because it's still going to be treated as `TIMESTAMP(0)`.

Comment: Illuminating! Thank you.